# Is it possible to call QR Scanner via Intent in GDK?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Native app for pairing Wifi on Glass contains QR scanner. Is it possible to use it via Intent in GDK? It would be useful for many use-cases.

Comment: I have created an issue requesting this Intent, vote please: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=344

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end I solved it by using ZBar instead of ZXing. It was easier to integrate.

I have based my implementation on glassware [GlassWifiConnect](https://github.com/jzplusplus/GlassWifiConnect).

Result can be seen in glassware [Glasquare](https://github.com/destil/glasquare/tree/master/code/Glasquare).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that's an in app feature of the setup app. I'm currently working on porting over the ZXing barcode scanning app to Glass. Feel free to steal from it. The source is located on [GitHub](https://github.com/BarcodeEye/BarcodeEye).

Also, one of the intents of this port is to allow other apps to request for barcode scanning, just like the original did, but it's not currently there yet. From a usability standpoint though, I feel that asking a user to install another app to do just the scanning is not ideal but it depends on user base or case. Either way, you are more than welcome to contribute if you feel that feature is necessary.

Comment: I have looked into your code, but it was too complicated. Too much classes I would need to copy into my own code. I would prefer a library which would hide all the details and only specify Intent API. At the end I used ZBar instead of ZXing, I based my implementation on https://github.com/jzplusplus/GlassWifiConnect